# Save Dictionaries to csv python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to save below dictionary to csv. Format of my dictionary content is:

```
dict = {0:[u'ab', u'cd'], 1:[u'b'], 2: [u'Ge', u'TT'], 3: [u'Stas'], 4: [u'sap', u'd3', u'ch99']}.
```

My code is:

```
 with open('Cr_pt.csv', 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(dict.keys())
        writer.writerows(zip(*dict.values())).
```

Below is the format I am trying to save in csv.

```
  1   2   3    4
  ab  Ge  Stas sap
  cd  TT       d3
               ch99
```

However I am getting only few values from dictionary in my final csv such as:

```
   1   2   3    4
  ab  Ge  Stas sap
```

Comment: What's your desired output format, given the dictionary input you provided?

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should avoid using `dict` as a variable name as it shadows [a built-in](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

The problem at hand is straightforward to solve with [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/);

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient='index').T.to_csv('Cr_pt.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
$ cat Cr_pt.csv 
0,1,2,3,4
ab,b,Ge,Stas,sap
cd,,TT,,d3
,,,,ch99
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution that writes to a CSV file directly without using the `csv` module and delimits each row with commas, creating a file of comma-separated values (CSV):

```
data = {0:[u'ab', u'cd'], 1:[u'b'], 2: [u'Ge', u'TT'], 3: [u'Stas'], 4: [u'sap', u'd3', u'ch99']}
delimiter = ","

with open('data.csv', 'w') as data_file:
    keys = [str(key) for key in data.keys()]
    values = data.values()
    max_values = max([len(value) for value in values])
    data_file.write(delimiter.join(keys) + "\n")
    for line in range(0, max_values):
        line_values = []
        for key in keys:
            try:
                line_values.append(data[int(key)][line])
            except:
                line_values.append("")
        data_file.write(delimiter.join(line_values) + "\n")
```

Output:

```
0,1,2,3,4
ab,b,Ge,Stas,sap
cd,,TT,,d3
,,,,ch99
```

In this format, it would be easier to read the data back from the file to another script, since the values are only comma-separated, not delimited by variable length whitespaces.